# probability fails two quizzes in a row before passes two quizzes in a row

Tags: probability

It's my first time to ask a math problem online :) looking forward to great explanations.
PROBLEM : Dave fails quizzes with probability 1/4, independent of other quizzes.
(d) What is the probability that Dave fails two quizzes in a row before he passes two quizzes in a row?

This problem is in 'Introduction to Probability 2nd edition', and it has solutions, but I simply could not understand the solution for this problem.
The solution says :
(If the event we're looking for is 'B', Failure 'F', Pass 'S')
**P(B) = P(FF) + P(SFF) + P(FSFF) + P(SFSFF) +...**

I understand rest of the solution after this part - how to calculate each of P(FF), P(SFF), ... and how to add it,
but I just got stuck on this part !
WHY IS "P(B) = P(FF) + P(SFF) + P(FSFF) + P(SFSFF) +..." ??
I thought failing two quizzes in a row is FF, passing two quizzes in a row is SS..
PLZ HELP ME AND MY POOR BRAIN with a super clear & easy explanation!

Comment: I guess that to be considered a "hit" a sequence 1)must end with FF 2)do not have to contain SS before FF happens. So for instance SSFSFF isn't a hit, since the two consecutive FF happened after two consecutive successes.

Comment: @nicola Wow thanx! It is really clear! Can I ask one more question if you please? If we calculate P(B) as P(FF) + P(SFF) + P(FSFF) + P(SFSFF) +..., What is the difference between "B : event we're looking for - Dave fails two quizzes in a row before he passes "two"quizzes in a row" and "C : event of Dave fails two quizzes in a row before he passes "one"quizz in a row" ? 
(B and C has single difference - before passing 2 quizzes vs. 1 quiz)
If those are same, I'm curious why we don't multiply P(SS) or P(S)at the end.

Comment: After 2 rolls it could be over because he either passed or failed 2 - but if it isn't over he passed and failed in one of two orders, so there are two scenarios A - he passed his last test, and B he failed his last test - now the chances of him going on to fail 2 are different in these cases I think you will see.  
In both cases his next test either ends it, or switches the case from B to A or A to B - from that, you can relate the two probabilities and solve them for cases A and B - if you then find the chances of failing two in scenarios A and B, you can calculate the overall prob.

Comment: I make it 7/52 which is borne out by a computer simulation - i can post some workings if you get stuck - I did it by thinking about the 4 different situations after the first two quizzes and making a relation between the two of those that were not settled

Answer (score 1):

See, the question says that we should find the probability that Dave fails two quizzes before passing 2 quizzes in a row. So for that we have CASE 1: Dave fails his first two quizzes given by P (FF); CASE 2: Dave passes the first quiz but fails the next two given by P (SFF); CASE 3: He fails the first, passes the 2nd and fails the next two given by P (FSFF); CASE 4: He passes the first, fails the 2nd, passes the 3rd and fails the next 2 given by P (SFSFF) and so on. Basically we find all cases where the sequence FF comes before SS and hence in the following ways the probabilities are calculated.
So, the next case is finding P (FSFSFF) as we don't want SS to come before FF.

Comment: Wow thanx, your explanation is really clear! 
Can I ask one more question if you please? 
If we calculate P(B) as P(FF) + P(SFF) + P(FSFF) + P(SFSFF) +..., What is the difference between "B : event we're looking for - Dave fails two quizzes in a row before he passes "two"quizzes in a row" and "C : event of Dave fails two quizzes in a row before he passes "one"quizz in a row" ? 
(B and C has single difference - before passing 2 quizzes vs. 1 quiz)
If those are same, I'm curious why we don't multiply P(SS) or P(S)at the end.

Comment: he has to fail 2 in a row before he passes 2 in a row - he can fail and pass any number where two do not fall in a row, which in practice means he has to alternate passing or failing until 2 in a row is achieved - that can lead to an infinite summation of of probabilites which is one way of doing it.

Comment: you might want to think about how after the first test there will be one of two scenarios, the next test will either cause the end of the trial or otherwise lead to the alternate scenario